# How to stratify split a multi-label, melted dataframe by unique IDs instead of rows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, train-test-split

**Note: I am not asking how to pivot a dataframe, I'm asking how to split a dataset into train, validation and test sets where the dataset is not only in multi-label and melted format, it also has to be split by unique customer ids, with stratification to ensure each split is proportionate.**

**The dataset that i have**

I have a df with a shape of around `(200000, 700)`. It is a multi-label (not multi-class as the labels are not mutually exclusive) with four labels and is in a melted format.

To illustrate my issue, here's a simplified example of the df:

| customer_id | month_year | label | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_1 | jan_2022 | label_1 | 1 |
| customer_2 | jan_2022 | label_1 | 1 |
| customer_2 | jan_2022 | label_2 | 0 |
| customer_2 | jan_2022 | label_3 | 1 |
| customer_2 | jan_2022 | label_4 | 1 |
| customer_3 | jan_2022 | label_1 | 1 |
| customer_3 | feb_2022 | label_1 | 0 |
| customer_3 | mar_2022 | label_1 | 1 |
| customer_3 | apr_2022 | label_1 | 1 |
| customer_3 | feb_2022 | label_3 | 0 |

There are 4 distinct labels in the df: `label_1`, `label_2`, `label_3`, `label_4` with the 'target' column indicating 0 or 1 for that label. It essentially represents the same information as a df with four seperate labels, but in a melted format.

The df captures the monthly snapshot of up to four target labels for each customer. This means that not every customer has all four labels, and each label itself might have more than one profile snapshot e.g. label for Jan 2022, Feb 2022, Mar 2022, and so on.

This variability in both labels and frequency per customer means that:

- a customer like `customer_1` might only have `jan_2022` snapshot of `label_1`.
- another customer like `customer_2` might have `jan_2022` snapshots of `label_1`, `label_2`, `label_3` & `label_4`.
- other customers like `customer_3` might have four months of snapshots for `label_1`: `jan_2022`, `feb_2022`, `mar_2022`, `apr_2022`, as well as a `feb_2022` snapshot of `label_3`.

**Why the df is in a melted format**

If we were to unmelt the df, it would look like this:

| customer_id | month_year | label_1 | label_2 | label_3 | label_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| customer_3 | jan_2022 | 1 |  |  |  |
| customer_3 | feb_2022 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| customer_3 | mar_2022 | 1 |  |  |  |
| customer_3 | apr_2022 | 1 |  |  |  |

And the absence of certain labels for certain months (not having 1/0) is exactly why the df has to be in a melted format, otherwise the model cannot be trained on it.

**The problem**

My problem is two-fold:

1. I first need to split this dataset into a training, validation &
   test set in such a way that each customer's records should only either be in
   the training, validation, & test set with no overlap.
2. The proportions of the multi-labels across each split should be consistent. I understand that it might not be feasible for each split to be completely proportionate, but it's important to attempt to have stratification.

**What i've tried so far:**

I've managed to solve the first part of the problem by using sklearn's `train_test_split` to split the list of unique customer ids into the train, val & test lists and then filtering the df by those lists:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_size = 0.7
val_size = 0.15
test_size = 0.15

# 1. Get the unqiue customer ids from the df as a list
unique_cust_list = df["customer_id"].unique().tolist()
 
 # 2. split the unique ids into train, val & test list 
train_id_list, remainder = train_test_split(unique_cust_list, test_size= val_size + test_size)
val_id_list, test_id_list = train_test_split(remainder, test_size=test_size / (val_size + test_size))

# 3. Filter the df using the 3 lists
train_df = df[df["customer_id"].isin(train_id_list)]
val_df = df[df["customer_id"].isin(val_id_list)]

test_df = df[df["customer_id"].isin(test_id_list)]
```

I'm stuck with the second problem of ensuring proportionality in each split.

I've looked into sklearn's `StratifiedShuffleSplit` and `StratifiedGroupKFold` but none of those natively support splitting a multi-label melted dataset by unique id.

In fact, I cannot seem to find any solutions online that is catered to unique nature of my dataset. I might possibily have to implement a custom stratification solution but I have no idea how to begin with this.

**End Result**

The ideal result is:

1. Each customer's records should only be in the train, validation or test sets.
2. The label distributions among the sets should be fairly consistent. For example, assuming the train dataset has these label distributions:

| Labels | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| label_1 | 91% | 9% |
| label_2 | 88% | 12% |
| label_3 | 95% | 5% |
| label_4 | 89% | 11% |

The validation and test datasets should also follow these similar distributions.

Comment: I see, then you should write a custom splitting logic. Maybe the pivoted intermediate could help.

Comment: @mozway Yes, this is the part that i'm stuck with, and i'm hoping that someone might have a solution for it

Comment: A client must only be assigned to a single dataset in accordance with the proportions (0.7, 0.15, 0.15), but the labels must be fairly distributed between the datasets. That's right ?

Comment: Your #2 is unclear, it would be ideal to provide an example output and to explain why

Comment: @Corralien Yes, that is the general idea

Comment: @mozway I've added some more explanations at the end of my question